# Does anyone know why Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is installing an ROS

Tags: command-line, kernel, security, canonical-livepatch, ros

Could someone explain why a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS keeps installing a robot on machine and a generic kernel that can't be updated so that I can comply with FIPS? It is driving me crazy trying to figure this out. All I want is a secure system that I know for a fact is secure. Everything looks good if I just used the software updater as I would never know anything was incorrect. But once I check things out in the terminal I can't even activate FIPS on my machine and my livepach kernel is disabled, Because of this generic kernel for "ROS". Is this normal? If so can I change it? Should I change it, should I even worry about it? Any thoughts?
Much thanks for any help ^-^

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Did you download an image from ubuntu.com?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1489915/edit) to provide specific package names. Also please add the complete output of `sudo apt update`.